# Extracting images from drawContour

Tags: python, image, opencv, contour

I am currently ingesting a video, and using createBackgroundSubtractorMOG() on each frame to get an image like this for each frame[image]

The original frame looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to be able to go through each of these frames and find the areas on the images that are "objects", and crop these areas from the original frame (before applying fgbg). I have tried using drawContours on the image and I get something like this.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this since I don't necessarily need each contour point returned by findContours, I would just like to figure out how to get a list of coordinates of a rectangle around the contoured image that I could then use to crop out the objects from the original image and save it to a file.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: `cv2.minAreaRect(points)`

Comment: You should give the original image. So we can decide the best binary image, then do findContours and other steps. Your binary image is not that good.